# Azure: Container did not start within expected time (WebApp)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, next.js

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy a webapp:

**ERROR - Container XXX_0 for site XXX did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 1800.4463925 sec**

I'm trying to deploy a node app. Using automatic deployment with a .deployment file. The .deployment file looks as follows:

```
# 1. KuduSync
if [[ "$IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT" -ne "1" ]]; then
  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;
.deployment;deploy.sh"
  exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync failed"
fi

# 2. Select node version
selectNodeVersion

# 3. Install npm packages for root directory
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/package.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  # echo "Running $NPM_CMD install --production for root directory"
  # eval $NPM_CMD install --production
  echo "Running $NPM_CMD install --production for root directory"
  eval $NPM_CMD install
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"
  ##################
  echo Building App...
  eval $NPM_CMD run build
  ##################
  echo Starting App...
  # eval $NPM_CMD run start
  # cd - > /dev/null
fi

#####################################################################################
echo "Finished successfully."
```

The package.json file has the following script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "echo 'work!!' && NODE_ENV=production && node server.js"
  }
```

And server.js is as follows:

```
const {
  createServer
} = require('http')
const next = require('next')
const app = next({
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
const routes = require('./routes')
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app)
console.log("HEYYYY");
// Without express
app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Ready on Localhost:80!!!");
    createServer(handler)
      .listen(80, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Ready on Localhost:80");
      });
  })
```

What I've gathered from research is that:

1. There is not enough time for the app to start
2. The port isn't open/ doesn't respond to a [ping at start up](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NoPing)

To solve (1) I  set WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT to 1800 (which is the max)

To solve (2) I set WEBSITES_PORT (in app setting) with a value of "80" to expose that port. (As per documentation)

Any others things I should try ?

PS the default docker log file outputs the following:

```
2018-10-15T14:32:59.946431939Z > XXX@1.0.0 start /home/site/wwwroot
2018-10-15T14:32:59.946455839Z > echo 'work!!' && NODE_ENV=production && node server.js
2018-10-15T14:32:59.946462839Z 
2018-10-15T14:33:00.249554126Z work!!
2018-10-15T14:34:41.634101502Z HEYYYY
2018-10-15T14:35:38.838555689Z  DONE  Compiled successfully in 48099ms14:35:38
2018-10-15T14:35:38.838868291Z 
2018-10-15T14:35:39.406086808Z Ready on Localhost:80!!!
2018-10-15T14:35:39.460029162Z Ready on Localhost:80
```

Answer (score 4):

- The recommended way to do this is to have node listen on `env.PORT`. This way the PORT is not hardcoded in the app and the system can pass it on via the Environment Variable.
- If a hardcoded port has to be used, and when using App Service in the "Code" scenario, use the App Setting PORT to indicate the value in code.
- If a hardcoded port has to be used, and when using App Service in the "Container" scenario, use the App Setting `WEBSITES_PORT` to indicate the value in code.
- If the port value matches what is in this log entry:  *"did not start within the expected time limit. Elapsed time "*, to what is in code, check the Listen IP address for the code. If the code is listening on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, then it will not be accessible outside that specific container, hence, the app will fail to start. To get past this, make the app code listen on `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this part?
>  To get past this, make the app code listen on 0.0.0.0

Comment: setting HOSTNAME to "0.0.0.0" in my dockerfile did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

For me setting both `-Port 80` and `-WEBSITES_PORT 80` in `Azure App Service Deploy` task, `App Settings` section in azure devops helped. It made docker to start with port 80 instead of 8000. It is in [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) of app setting usage for that task.