# Azure Web Services [Web App for Containers (linux)] - how to prevent timeout periodically

Tags: azure, web-services, timeout, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

There is error log in Web Services periodically:

> ERROR - Container XXX for site YYY did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.3790706 sec

I set below settings already mention in [Microsoft's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/) but still failed:

```
1. Use the EXPOSE instruction in your Dockerfile to expose port 3000.
2. Use the WEBSITES_PORT app setting with a value of "3000" to expose that port.
```

How to config to prevent this error?

Answer (score 6):

Similar issue found in [Azure: Container did not start within expected time (WebApp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52823025/azure-container-did-not-start-within-expected-time-webapp) with solution.

Adding Application Settings: WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT = 1800

Comment: I do not recommended using this setting. It will put your entire app service (web app) in limbo for 30 minutes. This does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi @Newteq Developer, do you have other solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried a bunch of different things, but nothing seemed to work. The main problem is caused because there is a problem with the start up of the application. So, the big problem with this approach is that you would deadlock your app service for 30 minutes before being able to try anything new

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the PORT like the code below, the AppService will use the PORT environment and it works for me.

Example about NestJS

```
  const port = process.env.PORT? parseInt(process.env.PORT) : 3000;
  logger.log(
    `Application is running on: http://localhost:${port}`,
  );
  await app.listen(port);
```

Hope it is helpful to you